# How to format an USB drive having multiple partitions under Windows 11?

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, windows-11, disk-management

I have an USB stick totalling 8GB. It has three "partitions":

[image]

- 41 MB Unallocated
- D: 2MB Fat
- the rest is unallocated

I want to completly format the USB drive. Yet when I do right click on D:\ and select format it will only format the 2.25MB partition:

[image]

I cannot delete the D:\ partition within Disk Management tool ("Create and format hard disk partitions"). When I right click it, all options are grayed out.

[image]

I tried ejecting the disk, but then it also disappears from the disk management tool.

(I assumed unmounting the D:\ drive would let me delete the partitions, yet as it appears: ejecting is not unmounting.)

How to format the entire USB stick using the Windows Disk Management tool?

Comment: What tool did you use to originally create the partition? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Use diskpart in cmd prompt, use the "clean" command once the proper usb device is selected. Now you should be able to format it.

Comment: Or a free third-party tool, such as DiskGenius.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that Windows protects EFI partition from being deleted. One is able to delete the partion via

- `diskpart` (Win + R, enter the command, a terminal windows with diskpart running will pop up)
- `list disk`, will print a list of all disks, e.g.:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         3726 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 2    Online          238 GB   450 MB
  Disk 3    Online          476 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 5    Online           57 GB    57 GB
```

- select your relevant disk. in my case, it's Disk five: `sel disk 5` (double check your disk numeber!)
- `list partition`

```
DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System            3968 KB  1988 MB

DISKPART> sel partition 1
```

And finally, deleted the partion via:

```
DISKPART> delete partition override
DiskPart successfully deleted the selected partition.
```

From the [source](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/delete-efi-system-partition.html), they also set an ID, yet that part both did not work nor was it necessary for me.

---

Now the entire USB stick was deleted:

[image]